# Returning an array using PDO

Tags: postgresql, pdo, php-7

I'm trying to use PDO using the following code, I want to select the array of values for the context_list, but it returns one record, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
try {
$sql2 = "SELECT area_easting, area_northing, context_number FROM excavation.contexts";
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$sth->execute();
  while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $easting_list = $row['area_easting'];
        $northing_list = $row['area_northing'];
        $context_list = $row['context_number'];
    }
}   

catch(PDOException  $e )
{
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}


echo "context list: ";
echo $context_list;
```

A partial solution:

> This worked:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT area_easting, area_northing, context_number FROM excavation.contexts");
$query->execute();
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $r->area_easting, '|';
    echo $r->area_northing;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

But Now I need to make the $r->area_easting accessible to the session, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Your query may return several records (provided they actually exist in the table).
Your code loops through all the records (with the `while` loop) but the values (`$easting_list`, `$northing_list` and `$context_list`) are overwritten in the loop.

I suggest the following changes to your code:

```
$easting_list = array();
$northing_list = array();
$context_list = array();
try {
    $sql2 = "SELECT area_easting, area_northing, context_number FROM excavation.contexts";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql2);
    $sth->execute();
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $easting_list[] = $row['area_easting'];
        $northing_list[] = $row['area_northing'];
        $context_list[] = $row['context_number'];
    }
}
catch(PDOException  $e )
{
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}

echo "context list: ";
echo implode(', ', $context_list);
```

Now all the values are stored in 3 arrays. `explode` is used to print a comma-separated list of all values in `$context_list` array.

Comment: Returns: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\gygaia_web\query_select.php for this line: echo explode(', ', $context_list);

Comment: I found a solution, I'll add it to the question for further comment

Comment: I wrote `explode` instead of `implode`. It should work now.